# How can I extract this api to an interface so I can mock it in my tests?

Tags: go

So currently I have a http handler that looks like:

```
type App struct {

}
func (a *App) someHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var api = slack.New("TOKEN")
        users = api.GetUsers()
}
```

I want to create an interface for this slack.New("...") call so that in my tests the api doesn't make network requests to slack.

How can I mock this New call?

The call New("TOKEN") returns a *Client, see the link below:

```
func New(token string, options ...Option) *Client {
    s := &Client{
        token:      token,
        httpclient: &http.Client{},
        log:        log.New(os.Stderr, "nlopes/slack", log.LstdFlags|log.Lshortfile),
    }

    for _, opt := range options {
        opt(s)
    }

    return s
}
```

https://github.com/nlopes/slack/blob/0f8db5050731c50359e319cf253af5b9997a2b1e/slack.go#L84

I haven't used interfaces that much so not sure if this can't be put in a interface since the call to New is like a constructor?

Comment: Define an interface with a method that matches `slack.New`'s signature, and pass a parameter of that interface's type to your `someHandler` method.

Comment: @jubobs I updated my question.  So I have the New() function and the api.GetUsers.  So I need to define 2 interfaces then right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mock the `slack.New` call itself, instead you have to create a mock that behaves like this `api` object.  To do this put the `api` onto the `App` struct but as an interface:

```
type SlackClient interface {
    GetUsers() []string
}

type App struct {
    api SlackClient
}

func (a *App) someHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { 
    users = a.api.GetUsers() 
}
```

You then have to move the call to `slack.New` into whatever constructs the `App` (for instance your main function or a `NewApp` constructor function):

```
app = App{api: slack.New("TOKEN")}
```

The *Client this returns has a `GetUsers` method on it so will match the interface we have defined.

The test then does something similar with a mock:

```
type mockSlackClient struct {

}

func (m *mockSlackClient) GetUsers() []string {
    return nil
}

func TestSomeHandler(t *testing.T) {
    appToTest := App{api: &mockSlackClient{})

    appToTest.someHandler(httptest.NewRecorder(), nil)
}
```

Again as the `*mockSlackClient` has a `GetUsers` method on it it will satisfy the interface so you will be able to use it on the `App`.